Can't edit Odoo17 on-premise email templates
I am unable to update any email templates via the Odoo UI, yet I have no trouble altering any other records or items. On my on-premise server, I have Odoo17 operating with nginx enabled.
The console indicates 403 Forbidden when I check, and I keep getting Connection Lost and it gets restored instantly.
ConnectionLostError: Connection to "/web/dataset/call_kw/mail.template/web_save" couldn't be established or was interrupted
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (web.assets_web.min.js:2877:71)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (rocket-loader.min.js:1:9405)

Editing is possible in that scenario. I terminated the nginx service and used the IP address to visit Odoo.
Has someone else encountered a similar problem?
